# Swift NumberFormatter just for thousand

Tags: ios, swift, numberformatter

I want to separator in 1000 after 1, but I'm getting separator for numbers >=10000
How I'm doing it:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.string(for: myNumber)
```

what I'm getting:

```
(lldb) po formatter.string(for: 1000)
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "1000"

(lldb) po formatter.string(for: 10000)
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "10 000"
```

why there is no separator in 1000?

Comment: It's using your local Local. Which locale is that?

Comment: @Alexander current locale is pl_PL

Comment: @Rob I'm curious in which locale i can test it? Changed it to US and still same

Comment: Ok guys, you are right. Changed region and language and there is separator but I will let it to depend on locale. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> why there is no separator in 1000?

This pattern, of omitting the grouping separator when there are only four digits, is not uncommon for languages that use a space as the separator.

As [Exceptions to digit grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Exceptions_to_digit_grouping) says:

> The International Bureau of Weights and Measures states that “when there are only four digits before or after the decimal marker, it is customary not to use a space to isolate a single digit”.

You will see this pattern in several locales that use space as the grouping separator.

---

This formatting is based upon the device’s settings (as represented by your current `Locale`). You can test to see what it looks like for other users in other locales by just temporarily changing your device settings.

I would be wary about manually adjust locale property of the formatter for desired output: Sure, one may do that for diagnostic purposes, but generally you do not want to change the locale of the formatter (with the obvious exception where you need some invariant format, for example, storing results in persistent storage or sending to a server).

Always use the device’s current locale so you honor the number formatting wishes of the end user.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is possibly a bug with the pl_PL locale in NumberFormatter. I recommend reporting the issue to Apple. You can use the Feedback Assistant app on macOS.

You could technically implement workarounds, ie hardcoding a locale or trying to do your own formatting, but it's generally not good practice to force a specific format on all users. And implementing formatting on your own can become a rabbit hole of edges cases and be prone to errors.